# Creating a request to the django model

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class paidparking(models.Model):
    adress = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Адрес парковки')
    carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Номер автомобиля')
    amountoftime = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество времени')
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Электронный адрес',null=True,blank=True )
    datetimepaidparking = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата и время оплаты')
    expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True,verbose_name='Дата начала срока действия')
    expirationtime = models.TimeField(null=True,verbose_name='Время начала срока действия')
    enddateandtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Окончание срока действия')
```

The form has 2 fields with date selection

[image]

In the function, I get the value from these fields

```
 startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
 enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
```

In the model, the `expirationdate` field. The date in this field is in the format %d.%m.%Y

I need to form a request to the django model. If the date in the `expirationdate` field falls between `startdate and enddate`, then all records must be retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [__range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) operator:

```
paidparking.objects.filter( expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate))
```

Comment: `paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate))
    return JsonResponse({'price': paymentparking.price, 'expirationdate': paymentparking.expirationdate})` When returning JSON to JS, I get an error AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'price'